# How to create db table with SQLite / SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a table in an existing db with SQLAlchemy/SQLite where I have to store a user and password, but it returns an error saying the column pwd doesn't exist!
Am I missing something? Am I messing it up?
I still didn't quite understand, I followed all steps in some online tutorial but nothing still.
Here is the class object that I developed, then from another register form I try to store the pw from the application, but the error should be here in this code:

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# flask imports
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from sqlalchemy import *

# create flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
# set sqllite db connection
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data-dev.sqlite')
engine= create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
# bcrypt extension init to app
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

# sqlite init to app
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
 
# define meta data for table
meta=MetaData()
userstable = Table('users', meta, Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True), Column('username', String, unique=True), Column('pwd', String))

# create table to sqlite 
meta.create_all(engine)

class User(db.Model):

    # user columns
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    pwd = db.Column(db.String(128))
 
    def __init__(self,username,pwd):
        #self.id=id
        self.username=username
        self.pwd=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(pwd)

# create user object
user = User('anish','23434')
# insert user object to sqlite
db.session.add(user)
# commit transaction
db.session.commit()
```

This is the error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError  OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named pwd [SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, pwd) VALUES (?, ?)] [parameters: ('ita_itf', '$2b$12$VmpTsd0o4uTLj0wGypGu7ujhzYHLlV8k9ekaIP1.yh5lUMMgOM4MC')]

Comment: THIS IS THE ERROR: ```sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) table user has no column named pwd
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (username, pwd) VALUES (?, ?)]
[parameters: ('ita_itf', '$2b$12$VmpTsd0o4uTLj0wGypGu7ujhzYHLlV8k9ekaIP1.yh5lUMMgOM4MC')]```

Comment: __tablename__ = "users"
will fix the issue, you need define table name as well , based on error it says table user while you created users. i have tested it as well , working at my end

Comment: Ah let me try then!

Comment: @ANISHKUMARMOURYA despite I add the tablename it returns the same error! the interesting thing is that I tested trying to comment the pwd column, and passing just id and username, it works!!! then I flash the query result as following; ```results = db.session.query(User).all()
        flash(results)```

Comment: and this is the output in my app!                                                                                        [<User 4>, <User 3>, <User 1>, <User 2>, <User 5>]

Comment: I don't get what's wrong with that pwd column, maybe I have by mistake previously created a table called "users" by testing the code just with two columns, and now it's kind of trying to re-create the same table.

Comment: then records are being inserted to db bud . you can mark this thread as solved .thanks

Comment: Indeed there was already a table called users! I changed the table name to user and it works now!!!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# flask imports
from flask import Flask 
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from sqlalchemy import *

# create flask app
app = Flask(__name__)
# set sqllite db connection
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data-dev.sqlite')
engine= create_engine(app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'])
# bcrypt extension init to app
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

# sqlite init to app
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
 
# define meta data for table
meta=MetaData()
userstable = Table('users', meta, Column('id', Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement=True), Column('username', String, unique=True), Column('pwd', String))

# create table to sqlite 
meta.create_all(engine)

class User(db.Model):
    # table name for User model
    __tablename__ = "users"

    # user columns
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    pwd = db.Column(db.String(128))
 
    def __init__(self,username,pwd):
        #self.id=id
        self.username=username
        self.pwd=bcrypt.generate_password_hash(pwd)

# create user object
user = User('anish','23434')
# insert user object to sqlite
db.session.add(user)
# commit transaction
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Makes no difference. Despite the fact that you haven't explained the change you made, `__tablename__` isn't required in `flask-SQLAlchemy`

Comment: you created users table while its looking for user table, so you need to define table name as well in model so it will pick correct table.

Comment: No you don't. _I_ also didn't create it.

Comment: cat data-dev.sqlite
?<<???{tableusersusersCREATE TABLE users (
 id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 username VARCHAR, 
 pwd VARCHAR, 
 PRIMARY KEY (id), 
 UNIQUE (username)
??F?anish$2b$12$XWxuKET2zqjPXmbhm.GJ.ubENEYPfNqlr99TZ1hfPhKv3/t1b4Hau
??

Comment: well it just table mismatch issue of ORM . you can get working through this . did you try above script? .it working at my end.i hope problem solved.

Comment: I removed __tablename__ makes no difference.

Comment: It won't, as I tried to explain to @ANISHKUMARMOURYA but he just ignored me

Comment: In class User you define the column types, but you don't actually create the table I think, firstly I should create the table? I suppose it says he can't find column pwd because maybe I didn't create the table properly, so I added the function Table outside the User class, but not sure this is correct

Comment: otherwise can I just create the table from sqlite command prompt in my linux? writing SQL directly? instead of creating it in the code? so I can check also if it's actually created properly. I just don't know how.

Comment: This explain how to create the table, it uses sqlalchemy and not Flask-sqlalchemy  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy_core_creating_table.htm

Comment: This explains how to declare the User object, but supposing the table already exists I think, so I basically mixed the two procedures   https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

Comment: Thank you Anish, and yes in my other module I do the following to store the pw        ```user = User(username="ita_itf", pwd=DICP_FTP_DESTINATION_PSW)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()```

Comment: Still I don't get why he doesn't find the pwd column :(